# why is my text in editText not centered horizontally?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, textview

i have this simple xml block:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
                        style="@style/textOnBg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:textColor="#516063"
                        android:textColorHint="#b4c8cf"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="25dp" >
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
```

however, when i put text in this editText the cursor is a bit to the left.

only after filling 80% of the editText the text seems centered.

```
<style name="textOnBg" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#32717f</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

**update**

tried this: but it didn't help

```
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
                        style="@style/textOnBg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: i meant editText. sorry

Comment: set width to fill parent and then try : android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: Could you post your style `textOnBg`?

Comment: There are 2 parts to the problem. You have not specified to center the text in edittext using `gravity`, and unless your edit text has a width that isnt just the length of the text.. then left aligned is the same thing as being centered. You should use `match_parent` width on edit text and linear layout, but it depends on the overall layout you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Give `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center"` to your `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:text="sdfsdfsdf"
    android:textColor="#516063"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColorHint="#b4c8cf"
    android:textSize="25dp" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: @EladBenda i also added `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: @EladBenda no need to give width as `match_parent` you can use `wrap_content` also

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify a set width for the `EditText` before the gravity can have an effect. Set it to `fill_parent` and see if it has any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Comment: @EladBenda You dont have any `gravity` property in `editText`, just `layout_gravity`, which is different

Comment: if you want the text at the center of the Edittext you want use this property. Using layout_gravity it only change views gravity not anything inside the view.

Comment: why is width:match_parent needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColor="#516063"
        android:textColorHint="#b4c8cf"
        android:textSize="25dp" >
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gravity like this:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
            style="@style/textOnBg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:textColor="#516063"
            android:textColorHint="#b4c8cf"
            android:textSize="25dp" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: The parent is a LinearLayout and your suggestion only applies to RelativeLayout..